# should i get ina scruff with this person, or what?

Tags: discussion

[2x oversampling by inserting zeros?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/46325/2x-oversampling-by-inserting-zeros/46331?noredirect=1#comment97613_46331)

[his/her user page](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/16827/la-conquista) has this: *"La Conquista
Stackexchange is a collection of stupids playing smart. I never met so many stupids in my whole life."*

Comment: Hi Robert, the guy is gone. Would you mind marking your question as answered? :)

Comment: it be done ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Please do not feed the trolls.]

Comment: hay Peter, did you whack that troll?  or his answer and the comments?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Looks like they deleted it without outside intervention.  And, in fact, have deleted their account. It should disappear in 14 hours.

Answer (score 4):

This person is either very young ("never... in my whole life") or has never met a mirror. Let Darwinian selection do its job.